# find does not go through all files in folder structure

Tags: command-line, scripts, find, convert, svg

I want to convert a massive bunch of wmf files (120860!) to svg in many subfolders (27 subfolder with many sub-subfolders each). I have this bash script that does

```
for i in `find -iname "*.wmf"`; do
  uniconvertor ${i} ${i%.wmf}.svg
done
```

but it never converts everything, it always stops somewhere in the middle. Some subfolders get converted, some not, some only partially.
Even if I start the shell script in all 27 first-level subfolders, only part of the files get converted.

What could be the problem?

Comment: ... any spaces in those filenames?

Comment: no, but spaces in the folder names - that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have line breaks in the names of your files or folders you should use a `while` instead of a `for` loop:

```
find -iname "*.wmf" | while read file; do
    uniconvertor "$file" "${i%.wmf}.svg" 
done
```

This avoids problems with spaces in names and with too much arguments when expanding the `...`

Comment: I replaced all spaces with underscores and it worked, but your solution probably is much more elegant... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must surround your `find ...` command with `$(  )` to substitute the output, thusly:

```
for i in $( find . -type f -iname '*.wmv` ) ; do ...
```

However, you're causing Bash to produce (and store internally) a list of 120,860 filenames before you process the first one. Also (you haven't described the format of the filenames), this technique mishandles filenames with Spaces in them, e.g. `A Big File.wmf`.

Read `man find`, especially, about `--print0`, read `man xargs`, especially about `-0`, read `man bash` and wrap your command in a script that runs `uniconverter` on each of its arguments, and use something like:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.wmv' -print0 | xargs -0 thescript
```

Be sure to read `man bash` and be very aware of any Spaces in your filenames.

@steeldriver: TQ for pointing out my error. Reading `man bash` shows:

```
 Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
       all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
       when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $  and  `  retain
       their  special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its
       special meaning only when followed by one of the following  characters:
       $,  `,  ", \, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted within double
       quotes by preceding it with a backslash.
```

So I overworried about Shell expansion.